# Handle gziped content generated by Unreal

Tags: html, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip, unreal-engine4

I just finished to pack a game made in Unreal4 for HTML5. I obtained several gziped files that I need to upload to make it work on my website so I can test the project.
The thing is, I'm new with this type of content. I've searched through the engine documentation but didn't found nothing about how to upload and use the files on a website.

Does anyone have any tip or any kind of material that I can read about it to start the implementation?

Thanks in advance for the help.

**Files generated by the engine:**
[image: Files generated by the engine]

***** UPDATE 08/10/2017 *****

So, I'm implementing this on Amazon S3 with CloudFront and this is what I found out that is needed to make it work:

1 - All the gziped files generated must be renamed if you're going to use Amazon S3. What you need to do is remove the "gz" part of the name.

2 - In the .html file generated by Unreal, there's a line that says:

```
return serveGzipped ? (name + 'gz') : name;
```

that must be editted to:

```
return serveGzipped ? (name) : name;
```

3 - Rename the .html file to index.html or create a new index.html file that redirects to the .html generated by Unreal.

4 - After you upload all your files to Amazon as a Static Website, you'll need to open your Amazon S3 folder that contains the files (it's called Bucket on Amazon) and add this information to the metadata of each gziped file:

```
'content-encoding'  :  'gzip'
```

This will make Amazon S3 recognize the file is gziped when needed.

5 - Grant public access for reading operations to all the files.

6 - Grant public access for reading operations and to "list objects" for the bucket. Also, implement this policy for the bucket:

```
"Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
```

All these steps will make Amazon recognize gziped files and serve them when needed. This also solve the problems with error 403 and 404.

But still, after all this, I'm facing this error:

[image: DataCloneError]

This happens when I use the new Wasm file generation for Unreal.

If I use the old Asm file generation, I receive no error message, but the screen keeps black:

[image: Black screen]

Does anyone knows how to solve any of these issues (the wasm clone error or the asm black screen)?

Comment: 1. Perhaps can you share with us the list of files packaged by the engine (I'll try to answer without it)

2. There is a Readme.txt in here, you should copy-past it's content here to help others reading here

Comment: 3. Perhaps should you also copy-past the .htaccess file in case of pb and to help other people

Comment: Added the list of files generated and content from readme and .htaccess file.

Comment: Thank you, but did you try to deploy and launch you project?

Comment: Hi @SergioAAV, did you make any progress on this?

Comment: Well, I'm gonna try to implement it now... I was searching for a good free web host that supports gzip, but didn't had much success. I'm gonna try with the Amazon service... I think I can make it work now, after I read your tips and analyse my files.

Comment: Nice. When it works, please le us know (along with any trouble you got to make it work)

Comment: @SRombauts I've updated the original post to explain the error I'm facing now.

Comment: Hi, seems to me that you forgot to add the Utility.jsgz file that was on your first screenshot but is missing from your S3 bucket. In fact, it seems that you are not using any compressed files anymore!?

Comment: @SRombauts I edited the original post to explain more clearly what I did to make gzipped files to work on Amazon S3 and what is the error I'm facing now.

Comment: Sorry, I've also encounter this kind of errors in other (local) HTML5 test but I cannot remember how I made it work then. I should try with a web server, but I don't know when I will have the time to do so...

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you have packaged something like this (from [UE4 AnswerHub](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/658699/html5-resources-to-learn-from.html)):
[image]

First of all, there is a "Readme.txt" file  packaged, you should read-it to understand how your files can be deployed to a web-server.

Basically, what you have to do :

1. You need to have appropriate access a folder of a Web server, that need to be configured

   1. Test with a basic "index.html" that this part is working
2. Copy all the packaged files into this folder

   1. You can rename the "XX-HTML5-Shipping.html" file to "index.html",
   2. or create a "index.html" with an HTTP redirection to the original filename (easier to update latter)
3. In particular, there is a ".htaccess" file made for the Apache2 web server

   1. you may need to configure your server "http.conf" file to authorize ".htaccess" override
   2. you may need to edit it to add configuration for "gz" files:

`<files *.gz>
  AddType "text/javascript" .gz
  AddEncoding gzip .gz
</files>`

Let me know if you have some any problem following this.